# How to run webpage with mediadevices.getusermedia on android webview

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, getusermedia

I have used `getusermedia()` in javascript to invoke webcam but when I open the same webpage in `webview` of android, the front camera doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

This answer deliberately ignores Android. This is Browser dependent. If there is an Android issue (which your question doesn't imply) I can extend this.

You need to pass through the correct constraints to getUserMedia e.g.

```
{
  video: {
    width: { 
      min: 480,
      ideal: 720,
      max: 1280
    },
    height: {
      min: 480,
      ideal: 720,
      max: 1280
    },
    facingMode: 'user'
  }
}
```

Important to note: If you ask for the user camera but request a resolution which is too large facingMode may be ignored and the browser might use the back facing camera if the back facing camera has the resolution you requested. You will not receive an error if this happens.

You query all devices via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices to see if your camera is not the right one.

Please also read:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices 
https://webrtchacks.github.io/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/